# using sequel gem with db2

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jdbc

How can I use Sequel gem to connect to db2 database, 
 I am trying below command,

```
 connection = Sequel.connect(:adapter => 'jdbc', 
   :driver => 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver',
   :host => 'jdbc:db2://myhostname/50000/dbname', 
   :user=> 'userid',
   :password=>'password')
```

but still unable to connect,kindly suggest if I am missing on anything. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get some kind of error message? How did you try to test that connection?

Comment: Was able to fix it ,                                                                                         require 'sequel'
require 'logger'
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
require  file path of sqljdbc4.jar'
require ‘file path of \db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar'
require ‘file path of \db2jcc_license_cu.jar'
require ‘file path of \db2jcc.jar'



connection = Sequel.connect(adapter: "jdbc",
                            url: "jdbc:db2://xyx.pqr.net:PORT/Databasename:user=username;password=password;",
 host: "xyz.net", port: "11111", database: "Databasename")

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: Issue was fixed with:

```
require 'sequel' 
require 'logger' 
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter' 
require 'file path of sqljdbc4.jar' 
require 'file path of \db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar' 
require 'file path of \db2jcc_license_cu.jar' 
require 'file path of \db2jcc.jar' 

connection = Sequel.connect(
  adapter: "jdbc", 
  url: "jdbc:db2://xyx.pqr.net:PORT/Databasename:user=username;password=password;", 
  host: "xyz.net", 
  port: "11111", 
  database: "Databasename
)
```